# Hidden HTTP Post in Javascript

Tags: javascript, http, post

I'm trying to do an HTTP Post using Javascript.
I'm using the code reported here:
[JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

and it works fine.

But I need to remain in the same page while the HTTP Post is sent.

How can I do?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

[AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)?

Answer (score 0):

do it inside of an iframe.

do it as an AJAX post

Answer (score 0):

I know it seems to be the perpetual hammer (Because it is) but try using jQuery. then you can do a real simple jQuery post

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
  dataType: dataType
});

or 
the shortest method if you don't need a return..

$.post("postTo.php", { name: $('#name').val(), data: $('#data').val(); } );

Answer (score 0):

AJAX

> ```
> $('.button').click(function() {
>
>  $.ajax({
>   type: "POST",
>   url: "whateveryourphpfileis.php",
>   data: { whatyouare: "sending" }
> })
>
> });
> ```
>
> [How to Call a PHP Function on the Click of a Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738329/how-to-call-a-php-function-on-the-click-of-a-button)